# Turn button unfocusable

Tags: xamarin.forms

Entry is in focus, soft keyboard is shown.

Clicking on another visual element (In this case, the Grid) causes entry to lose focus,

and the keyboard to hide:

```
<Entry x:Name="SearchBox"
       Grid.Column="1"
       Text="{Binding AddressSearchText}" />
<Grid Grid.Column="2">
    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ClearSearchCommand}" />
    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
    <Image Source="{customControls:ImageMultiResource cross}"
           Aspect="AspectFit"
           HeightRequest="18"
           WidthRequest="18"
           VerticalOptions="Fill"
           InputTransparent="True" />
</Grid>
```

I want the user to be able to click on the Grid button and have the Entry still in focus,

with the keyboard showing.

How can I make the Grid unfocusable, so it doesn't cause the Entry to lose focus?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the Entry active in the command .

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ClearSearchCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference SearchBox}, Path=.}" />
```

```
ClearSearchCommand = new Command((arg)=> {

    var entry = arg as Entry;
    entry.Focus();
    //...       
            
 });
```

Comment: This causes the keyboard to flicker out and in, which I am trying to avoid.
I am basically asking where is the IsFocusable property on visual elements I'm used to from WPF, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Could you share your sample so that I can test it on my side directly ?

Comment: I went with another solution, to have the clear button as part of the Entry itself. Made it in the Entry's renderer, that way the Entry doesn't lose focus when clicking on it, and I can expose the command from my extended Entry.